# Cakephp with google map API by marcferna / CakePHP-GoogleMapHelper

Tags: php, google-maps, cakephp

currently Im using this API by marcferna / CakePHP-GoogleMapHelper 
https://github.com/marcferna/CakePHP-GoogleMapHelper
This API is good to me but I need to draw direction from current location

im looking at the getDirection() function in googleMapHelper.php but still can figure out any way to get current Location lat and lng value

```
var start = new google.maps.LatLng({$position['latitude']},{$position['longitude']});
var end = new google.maps.LatLng({$position['latitude']},{$position['longitude']});
var request = {
    origin:start,
    destination:end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.{$travelMode}
};
```

I have already edit the function for my own 
Now I can get the END lat,lng 
I need to get the START lat and lng value to finish this function but cant find anyway to do it
Already try to use navigator.geolocation before these code but still not working
Anyone get a solution?
thanks in advance

Comment: I use [this helper](http://www.dereuromark.de/2010/12/21/googlemapsv3-cakephp-helper/) which has a current Location feature - and shows how to use it in case you need it manually. See the source code of the helper.

Comment: Thank you ! But i dont really want to use 1 more helper just to get current location.In case i cant find a way else ,i will use that.ty

Comment: In that case see the docs of google: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation - this is not a cakephp question then.

Comment: I've used it already but still not work cause needed destination's lat lng properties is inside a function and some how i cant implement your link into that function getDirection() function in googleMapHelper.php